# Basic C hangman code problems

Tags: c

Hey guys im learning C and i started programming a Hangman Game. That should be played over 1 word and i choosed "informatik".

What i want to do is asking for users name and then start.

```
#include<stdio.h>            
 int main() {
int correct = 0;
int mistake = 0;
int number = 0;
char name[20];
char Word[]={'i','n','f','o','r','m','a','t','i','k'};
char guessStatus[]={'_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','\0'};
char guess;
printf("##### Welcome to Hangman #####\nWhat is your Name?\n");
scanf(" %s", name);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Hello %s!\n", name);                                                                               
   while (mistake <=10 && number<10) {
    printf("Guess a letter: ");
    guess = getchar();
    printf("%c", guess);
    correct = 0;
    for (int search=0; search<10; search++)
    {                                                


        if (guess == Word[search]){
            number++;
            guessStatus[search] = Word[search];
            correct = 1;
        }
    }
    if (correct == 0){
        mistake++;
        printf("%c is wrong!\nYour Status is: %s\nYou have %i tries left\n", guess,guessStatus,10-mistake);
    }
        else {
            printf("Good job %s!\nYour Status is: %s\nYou have %i tries left\n", name,guessStatus,10-mistake);
        }

}
```

}

Problem is when i run the code and enter any letter, program counts "enter" also as a letter.I used fflush(stdin) as a hope even i don't know anything about it but didn't work :)
Problem output like:

Welcome to Hangman

What is your Name?
john
Hello john!
Guess a letter:

is wrong!
Your Status is: __________
You have 9 tries left
Guess a letter: i
iGood job john!
Your Status is: i_______i_
You have 9 tries left
Guess a letter:

is wrong!
Your Status is: i_______i_
You have 8 tries left

I don't know how to deal with it.Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: What does "it [..] didn't work" mean? Did it crash? Did you get an error message? What error?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior

Comment: If you do not want "enter" to count as a letter, then add `if (guess=='\n') continue;` or something like that. But it would be better to check for letters: `if (guess < 'a' || guess > 'z')`, but the details will vary with your locale and vocabulary.

Comment: it didn't crash. it works actually but works wrong. when i put any correct word like "i". first it counts "i" as correct and puts into guessStatus and mistake-number doesn't change. then(without entering any letter again) it counts "Enter" key as a letter and its wrong.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the gethcar(); will be ok for read the \n:

```
#include <stdio.h>            
 int main() {
int correct = 0;
int mistake = 0;
int number = 0;
char name[20];
char Word[]={'i','n','f','o','r','m','a','t','i','k'};
char guessStatus[]={'_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','_','\0'};
char guess;
printf("##### Welcome to Hangman #####\nWhat is your Name?\n");
scanf(" %s", name);
getchar(); // add this line
printf("Hello %s!\n", name);                                                                               
   while (mistake <=10 && number<10) {
    printf("Guess a letter: ");
    guess = getchar();
    printf("%c", guess);
    correct = 0;
    for (int search=0; search<10; search++)
    {                                                


        if (guess == Word[search]){
            number++;
            guessStatus[search] = Word[search];
            correct = 1;
        }
    }
    if (correct == 0){
        mistake++;
        printf("%c is wrong!\nYour Status is: %s\nYou have %i tries left\n", guess,guessStatus,10-mistake);
    }
        else {
            printf("Good job %s!\nYour Status is: %s\nYou have %i tries left\n", name,guessStatus,10-mistake);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: yes works :) and i have to put it to while statement too(between guess=getchar(); and printf("%c", guess);. but why? shouldn't user enter his word with "enter" key?

Comment: Googel "scanf line buffer" will know.

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work
Use

```
scanf(" %c",&guess);
```

instead of

```
guess = getchar();   //remove this line
printf("%c",  guess); //remove this line also
```